# Finding E[XY] to be used in Covariance in a joint probability question

Tags: probability, expectation, covariance, correlation

> A fair die is rolled $90$ times. Let $X$ be the total number of trials
>   when faces having $2$ or $3$ dots appear and $Y$ be the total number
>   trials when faces having $3$ or $4$ dots appear. Find $\rho(X,Y)$

I found $EX=EY=30$ and $Var(X)=Var(Y)=np(1-p)={90.5\over36} = 25/2$
Now I need to find $E[XY]$ in order to use it in $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[X]$ formula. After that I can find $\rho(X,Y)$ but I couldn't find $E[XY]$.

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could express $X$ and $Y$ as sums of indicator functions, and compute expressions from there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $W_1$ be the number of times $2$ comes up, $W_2$ be the number of times $3$ comes up, $W_3$ be the number of times $4$ comes up. Then $W_1,W_2,W_3$ are i.i.d. $\operatorname{Binomial}(90,\frac16)$, and $X=W_1+W_2, Y=W_2+W_3$, giving $$E(XY)=E[(W_1+W_2)(W_2+W_3)]$$
The rest is easy due to independence of $W_i$'s.

Comment: The $W_i$ are not independent.  Every time a 2 comes up is one less time a 3 can come up.  But you can evaluate $\mathsf E(W_1W_2)$ as $\mathsf E(W_1\,\mathsf E(W_2\mid W_1))$, since $(W_2\mid W_1)\sim\mathcal{Bin}(90-W_1, 1/5)$.

Comment: "Every time a 2 comes up is one less time a 3 can come up." - why is that?

Comment: There are $90$ rolls. When given $W_1$ twos, you cannot have more than 
$90−W_1$ threes. Therefore there will be a negative correlation. Indeed $\mathsf {Cov}(W_1,W_2)=−5/2$ (keywords: multinomial distribution)